# NSHTTPCookieStorage UTF-8 cookie name value is truncated

Tags: ios7, cookies, nshttpcookie, nshttpcookiestorage

In an iOS 7 app I'm using `NSHTTPCookieStorage` to store cookies in the `sharedHTTPCookieStorage`.

One of the cookies I'm receiving has a name value with the non-ASCII word "Søren" in it. I can see the cookie being set in an HTTP trace, but the cookie held in `sharedHTTPCookieStorage` is truncated after the "S" in "Søren". None of the subsequent cookies being set in the HTTP response header are stored in `sharedCookieStorage`. In fact the offending cookie is stored in truncated form twice, almost as if the framework tries to parse it again and then gives up.

RFC2965 states:

> NAME=VALUE
>         REQUIRED.  The name of the state information ("cookie") is NAME,
>         and its value is VALUE.  NAMEs that begin with $ are reserved and
>         MUST NOT be used by applications.

```
  The VALUE is opaque to the user agent and may be anything the
  origin server chooses to send, possibly in a server-selected
  printable ASCII encoding.  "Opaque" implies that the content is of
  interest and relevance only to the origin server.  The content
  may, in fact, be readable by anyone that examines the Set-Cookie2
  header.
```

I'm configuring `NSHTTPCookieStorage` as follows:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *sharedCookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
[sharedCookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:(NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways)];
```

I presume this is related to `NSHTTPCookieStorage`, rather than `NSURLResponse`. Do I need to do anything additional to handle a UTF-8 cookie name value?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem ? I'm facing the same one :/